# What sort of data is stored in cpu registers

Tags: operating-system

I know cpu registers are used for fast access. But could anyone give me an example of the data content stored in? Why these data are so imporant and have to be stored by operating system during context switching?

Comment: You may imagine that pointer to the next instruction which should be fetched from the memory and then executed is stored there (among other useful things). But I see that you mix concepts of different levels. OS stores state of the previous process during the context switch and fills registers with the processes' data (oversimplifying here).

Answer (score 1):

I would place registers in two groups:

1. System Registers
2. Registers that define the process state

System registers do not change with process contexts. Classically, the second group of registers includes:

1. A processor status register
2. General registers
3. Memory mapping registers

You seen to be most interested in #2 from the call of your question. For simplicity, I will use the VAX processor as the working example (The Intel Kludge-On-A-Chip is overly complex).

The VAX has 16 32-bit registers (R0 - R15). Some of those registers (R12–R15) have have special purposes:

PC = Program Counter points to the next instruction to execute
SP = Stack pointer points to bottom of the stack for the current mode.
AP = Argument Pointer points to the arguments to a function
FP = Frame Pointer used to restore the stack after a function call completes.

That leaves R0–R11 for general use.

R6-R11 can be used by programmers at will.
R0-R5 can be used by programmers but some instructions change their values.

The registers are 32 bits. They can then store:

1. One-Byte signed or unsigned integer
2. Two-byte signed or unsigned integer
3. Four-byte signed or unsigned integer
4. Four-byte floating point

You can do something like these:

```
ADDL3 R0, R1, R2 ; Add contents of R0 and R1 and store the result in R2
ADDF3 R0, R1, R2
```

In the first case, the processor treats the contents of R0 and R1 as 32-bit signed integers. In the second case, it treats the contents of R0 and R1 as 32-bit floating point values.

The interpretation of the register contents depends upon the instruction being executed. Thus, the two instructions above are likely to store different values in R2, even if they have the same values in R0 and R1.

Larger data types, adjacent registers can be combined.

```
 ADDD3 R0, R2, R4
```

This adds the contents of R0/R1, to the contents of R2/R3, and stores the result in R4/R5, treating the contents of all the register pairs as 64-bit floating point values.

You can even do

```
ADDH3  R0, R4, R8
```

This adds the contents of R0/R1/R2/R3 to the contents of R4/R5/R6/R7, and stores the result in R8/R9/R10/R11, treating the contents of all the register quads as 128-bit floating point value.

The VAX has character and come complex matching instructions that use R0-R5 for special purposes (such as loop counters). These are instructions with long execution that can be interrupted. Using the registers to maintain the state of the instruction allows the instruction to be restarted midstream when the process is restarted.

Programmers use R0-R5. There is no problem with that as long as you don't use the instructions that disrupt them.

By Convention R0 and R1 are used for function return values.

So these are the kinds of things you do with registers.

Answer (score 0):

They are not for fast access. They are the core of the cpu and every operation must be done on them. Cpu can add two numbers after you move them from memory to the registers, for example.

Comment: Some systems do memory to memory operations without registers other than the PC.